# Using a photoresistor to control a relay

Tags: arduino

G'day,

I'm trying to use a photoresistor to control a relay. My idea is if the photoresistor value is under 300 turn the relay on and if under 300, turn the relay off. Seems fairly straightforward to me, but it's not working and I'm not sure why.

As of right now, my code compiles and uploads, but it seems like the relay is getting a small current from the Arduino on its digital pin (it's flashing the relay package LED). Even if I take the photoresistor circuit out of the equation.

```
int sens = A0; //Photoresistor
int butt = 53; //Button
int rel = 51;  //Relay
int sensVal;   //Photoresistor Value


void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(butt, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(rel, OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  sensVal = analogRead(sens);
  Serial.print("Raw val from sens= ");
  Serial.println(sensVal);
  delay(500);

  if (analogRead (sens) < 300);
  {
    digitalWrite (rel, HIGH);
  }
  if (analogRead (sens) > 300);
  {
    digitalWrite (rel, LOW);
  }
  

  
  //if (digitalRead (butt) == HIGH)
  //{
  //  digitalWrite (rel, LOW);
  //}
  //if (digitalRead (butt) == LOW)
  //{
  //  digitalWrite (rel, HIGH);
  //}
}
```

ignore the comments, that's for another part I'm working on.

Any advice would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.

I changed the if statement around a little.

```
if (analogRead (sens) < 400)
  {
    digitalWrite (rel, HIGH);
    delay (1000);
  }
  else if (analogRead (sens) > 400)
  {
    digitalWrite (rel, LOW);
  }
```

Hopefully others can lern from my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help you:

`digitalWrite (rel, (analogRead(sens) <= 400) );`